# Is there any way to get the XPath or CSS path of an element using Java?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, xpath, firebug

I am trying to get the XPath and CSS path of an element using Java. I have used jsoup to parse the HTML and I am getting the CSS path, but in some cases it is returning the wrong path. (I am matching it with Selenium generated paths.)

I am using this code to generate CSS path
my element is "s-Rectangle_44"

```
<div id="s-Rectangle_44" class="rectangle firer click commentable">
  <div class="clipping">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="valign">
        <span id="rtr-s-Rectangle_44_0"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And selenium is giving css path as css=#s-Rectangle_44 > div.clipping > div.content > div.valign while I am getting array Index out of bound exception.I need to get the XPath also. Is there any other method to get this? Can I use Firebug with Java?

```
public static String getCssPath(Element el) {
  if (el == null)
    return "";

  if (!el.id().isEmpty())
    return "#" + el.id();

  StringBuilder selector = new StringBuilder(el.tagName());
  String classes = StringUtil.join(el.classNames(), ".");
  if (!classes.isEmpty())
    selector.append('.').append(classes);

  if (el.parent() == null)
    return selector.toString();

  selector.insert(0, " > ");
  if (el.parent().select(selector.toString()).size() > 1) {
    selector.append(String.format(":nth-child(%d)",
        el.elementSiblingIndex() + 1));
  }

  return getCssPath(el.parent()) + selector.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use Xpath and also firebug too.

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example for a wrong CSS path you got and what you expected to get. Firebug cannot be connected with Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read XML using XPath in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Comment: @SebastianZartner I don't want to read XML using XPath.I don't have XPath, I have an id of an element now I have to parse the html file and find the XPath and CSSPath of that element.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the intention. Anyway, please post more info on what you've tried so far. See also my first comment.

Comment: While I provided a general answer how to get the XPath and CSS path for an element, it's still unclear, for which element(s) you want to get the paths and what path(s) you actually expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CSS path

According to the [jsoup API reference](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) an `Element` has a [`cssSelector()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#cssSelector%28%29) function, which returns the related CSS path.

This function simply returns `#s-Rectangle_44` for your element with the ID `s-Rectangle_44`.

## XPath

If you can assume that every element you want to match has an ID, then this code may be sufficient:

```
String getXPath(Element el)
{
  return "//*[@id='" + el.id() + "']";
}
```

Regarding your example this would return `//*[@id='s-Rectangle_44']` for your element with the ID `s-Rectangle_44`.

There is also [an answer to a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5046246/432681), which has code for absolute paths.

---

Firebug's code (written in JavaScript) has [functions for getting the CSS path](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/86f461babda96a14b64f38da6db4546bfd10b1d9/extension/content/firebug/lib/css.js#L424-L453) and [functions for getting the XPath](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/b4adc6fcf8ba769eebb7a25044eb840b750282b0/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js#L21-L61), which generate absolute paths and could be translated to Java.

*Note that Firebug is under BSD license.*

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you tell me what is the difference between Xpath generated by Firebug and the Xpath generated by selenium and which one should be preferred.

Comment: Firebug returns an absolute XPath, while Selenium generates relative ones. There is no general answer for which one is better. It depends on your requirements. I suggest you to read the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) for further information about its syntax. With that knowledge you should be able to decide what fits your needs.

Comment: Do you mean a way to implement the source code of Selenium IDE into your Java environment?

Comment: yes i need the basic functionality of selenium IDE like command , target value through the code

Comment: Selenium IDE is written in JavaScript like all Firefox extensions. The [code can be found on the Google Code page of Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/ide/main/src/content/locatorBuilders.js?r=967286a7dc4acae58e95d53435c272a69b115d87#255). The code is under the Apache License 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, I am not able to figure out how to use it is there any documentation available for this code. What i need to do is that I have an id of an element like "rtr-s-Rectangle_44_0" in above example and I need to get the command, target value for that element(id).

Comment: There's a [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list) available for Selenium, though I fear there's no documentation of that specific methods. So you should [ask the team behind Selenium](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-developers) to get to know how their code works.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend to make your own XPath manually, because sometimes you need to use other attributes than "id" and classes like e.g. "data-id" when a developer uses it to store some properties.

Another way to get an XPath for an element is via the developer panel in Chrome. Just right-click the element and click *Copy XPath*. But it copies an absolute XPath with ID.