# Given a Node, how can I select the equivalent Node in a Document?

Tags: java, xml, dom

My caller is handing me an `org.w3c.dom.Node` and an `org.w3c.dom.Document` that serves as its [owner document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getOwnerDocument--).  The supplied `Node`, in other words, is guaranteed to be parented in the supplied `Document`, and represents the `Node` in that `Document` against which some work should be performed.

I am now in a position where I need to effectively clone the `Document` (I need to perform modifications, and cannot modify the source.)

Obviously, if I do that, the `Node` I still have in my hand is not owned by the new `Document` resulting from the clone.  I have now effectively lost the selection in the cloned `Document`.

However, I know that there will be a `Node` in that cloned document that is exactly equal to the `Node` I have in my hand.  I need to find it.

What is the best way to accomplish this, short of plowing through the whole `Document` and calling [`isEqualNode(Node)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#isEqualNode-org.w3c.dom.Node-) on each one?

I thought perhaps there would be some way to say `document.find(myUnparentedNode)`, but no such method exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could generate an XPath that describes the position of the node in the old document and then apply that to the new document. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5046174/1362755) for approaches how to do that.

If it's possible for you to modify the node before cloning just give it a unique attribute that doesn't collide with anything else (e.g. generated randomly) that you can then locate in the cloned document.

If it already has an id, just use that.

Comment: Thanks; can't do any of these things, but that's not the fault of your answer.  :-)  I'll see if I can punt cloning up higher in the process so I can work on the `Document` directly.