# Using XPath to compare two XML objects for exact equality

Tags: xml, xpath

When I have two XML objects, how can I compare them for exact equality (all the same nodes and attributes and values) using XPath?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In XPath 2.0 use the standard function [deep-equal()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal).**

Xpath 1.0 doesn't have such a function, therefore the comparison needs to be performed within the language hosting XPath.

**You can use this solution in case you must use XPath 1.0**: **[Generate/get xpath from XML node java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java)** to get a collection of XPath expressions for every node of `Document1` and another collection of XPath expressions for every node of `Document2`. Then compare the two collections -- they should have the same number of expressions each and the expressions must be equivalent.

**Alternatively**, you can generate just verify that the two collections contain the same number of expressions and apply each of the expressions for `Document1` on `Document2`.

Answer (score 5):

XPath 2.0 has a function deep-equal for that: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-deep-equal. XPath 1.0 has nothing comparable, you would need to roll your own, in whatever host language you use XPath 1.0 with.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a combination of XSLT 1.0 and Bash to compare specific nodes with each other based on their md5sums.

Using the test="$index=$navigator", because I couldn't copy-of based on a node[$navigator] directly.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:ns="http://www.example.org">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="navigator"/>
    <xsl:param name="part"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/ns:mappings/ns:mapping">
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
        <xsl:if test="$index=$navigator">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$part='source'">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ns:source/ns:taxonpath"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$part='target'">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ns:target/ns:taxonpath"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$part='mapping'">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```sh
mappingcount=$(cat mapping.xml | grep "<mapping>" | wc -l)
counter=1

while [  $counter -lt $mappingcount ]; do
    sourcehash=$(xsltproc --stringparam navigator $counter --stringparam part source compare.xslt mapping.xml | md5sum | cut -d " " -f1)
    targethash=$(xsltproc --stringparam navigator $counter --stringparam part target compare.xslt mapping.xml | md5sum | cut -d " " -f1)

    if [ "$sourcehash" == "$targethash" ]; then
        xsltproc --stringparam navigator $counter --stringparam part mapping compare.xslt mapping.xml
    fi
    let counter=counter+1
done
```

And a part of the mapping.xml

```
<mappings xmlns="http://www.example.org">
  <mapping>
    <source>
      <taxonpath>
        <taxon>
          <id>c001f86a-4f8f-4420-bd78-381c615ecedc</id>
          <entry>Aardrijkskunde</entry>
        </taxon>
        <taxon>
          <id>65c33fa0-420a-4399-a6f8-595294179df3</id>
          <entry>Weer en klimaat</entry>
        </taxon>
      </taxonpath>
    </source>
    <relationship>ter info</relationship>
    <target>
      <taxonpath>
        <taxon>
          <id>c001f86a-4f8f-4420-bd78-381c615ecedc</id>
          <entry>Aardrijkskunde</entry>
        </taxon>
        <taxon>
          <id>65c33fa0-420a-4399-a6f8-595294179df3</id>
          <entry>Systeem aarde</entry>
        </taxon>
      </taxonpath>
    </target>
  </mapping>
</mappings>
```