# Difference between XElement.CreateNavigator() and XPathDocument().CreateNavigator()

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, base-class-library

The following test fails. r1 seems to be missing angle brackets, does anyone know way? I imagine its some sort of encoding error?

```
var nav1 = XElement.Load(stream).CreateNavigator(); 
var nav2 = new XPathDocument(stream).CreateNavigator();

using (var r1 = new StringWriter())
using (var r2 = new StringWriter())
{
  xslt.Transform(nav1, null, r1);
  xslt.Transform(nav2, null, r2);

  r1.ToString().Should().Equal(r2.ToString());
}
```

The problem here is not as far as I can tell semantically equivalent but lexically different xml, but that the resulting xml in the r1 case is missing it's xml tags. Interestingly, using `var nav3 = XElement.Load(stream).CreateReader();` works fine.

Comment: Good question, +1. Yes, we do need robust XML comparison tools. I have built my own and it isn't too dificult to do so.

Comment: Does this happen with any XML document or only with a specific one? I want to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Xml: http://pastebin.com/m4MQVUaj XSLT: http://pastebin.com/D7nV4VvR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comparing two XML documents using their string representation is not a good idea**. While the two documents may be equivalent, they still could have many lexical differences, among them:

- Different prefixes bound to the same namespace.
- Use/not use CDATA sections
- represent/not-represent as strings inherited namespace nodes
- use quotes vs apostrophes
- use vs not-use character entities.
- ..., etc.

I would recommend a better way of doing this -- there are many **[xmldiff tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx)**. You could also build your own XML comparison tool (as I have done for myself) based on my answer to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java/4747858#4747858)**.

**UPDATE**:

After clarifications from the OP:

> "The problem here is not as far as I can tell semantically equivalent
> but lexically different xml, but that the resulting xml in the r1 case
> is missing it's xml tags"

**I investigated and came up with the following conclusion**:

The XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable, XsltArgumentList, Stream) works with either XmlDocument or XPathDocument as the first argument, as is **[described in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163434.aspx)**.

```
Parameters     
   inputType: System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable An object    
              implementing the IXPathNavigable interface. In the Microsoft .NET Framework, this
              can  be either an XmlNode (typically an XmlDocument), or 
              an XPathDocument containing the data to be transformed.
```

As the Navigator created from an XElement obviously doesn't fit in this category, the reported problem is observed.

**Solution**:

Change:

```
var nav1 = XElement.Load(stream).CreateNavigator();
```

to:

```
var nav1 = XDocument.Load(stream).CreateNavigator();
```

**Here is complete code that has been verified to work as expected**:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TestLINQ_Xml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test();
        }

        static void test()
        {
            XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
            xslt.Load(@"C:\temp\delete\XSLT.xsl");

            FileStream stream = 
              new FileStream(@"C:\temp\delete\sourceXML.xml", FileMode.Open);

            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
            var nav1 = xdoc.CreateNavigator();

            stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var nav2 = new XPathDocument(stream).CreateNavigator(); 

            using (var r1 = new StringWriter()) using (var r2 = new StringWriter()) 
            {   xslt.Transform(nav2, null, r1); 
                xslt.Transform(nav1, null, r2); 

                string  res1 = r1.ToString();
                string  res2 = r2.ToString();

                Assert.AreEqual(res1, res2);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Point taken, but the question is not really about xmldiff, but about why the output would be different in one of the cases - it actually does not contain any xml tags at all once I do ToString().

Comment: @George Mauer: I have updated my answer with what I believe is the reason for the problem. I also provide a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your result. My input XML contains 2 namespaces, in output XMLs namespaces are defined in different order. You can check your output byte by byte and find differences.