# Find the control XPath on Focus in WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, xpath, browser

I had developed a windows application 
with WebBrowser control, which can interact with windows control using this sample provided

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

But my need is when user focus an control, that controls XPath need to be send to my windows application

**For that two main needs are their**

1. Need to set javascript event to all controls (can it be commonly configured in single control)
2. that javascript need to find xpath and send

Can any one help me in doing this

Comment: Do you mean that given a node (element or other type???) in an XML document, you need an XPath expression that selects that node? If so, a complete solution is provided in my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java