# Find the xpath of selected item of XML doc loaded into a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xpath, .net-4.0

I have an XML document which I have loaded in to a WPF TreeView (thanks to http://blogs.intuidev.com/post/2009/12/28/XML_To_TreeView.aspx ) in a .Net4 windows app. what I would like to do is when a user selects a node is to display the xpath to the selection.

How would I do this?

Alternatively I have the xml also in a textbox would it be possible to show the xpath of selected text in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Given an XML element, one can build an XPath expression that selects exactly that element**.

**See this XSLT 1.0 solution**:

**[Generate/get xpath from XML node java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java/4747858#4747858)**