# How to enumerate all xpath of the webpage

Tags: xpath, browser-automation

How to enumerate all xpath of elements displayed on a specified URL or webpage based on exact matched or unique objects?

Could someone provide any sample or reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get xpaths for all leaf elements from XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064951/how-to-get-xpaths-for-all-leaf-elements-from-xml)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is what you mean but an xpath of

```
“//*”
```

Should return all elements on your webpage in a list you can iterate.