# It is possible to get the XPath of a SimpleXML element?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

After I find a special element, I want to get  its XPath. Is there any possibility to get the XPath of an SimpleXML element? Something like:

```
$xPathString = $element->getXpath();
```

I need the XPath in order to pass it to the 'click' method of a Selenium test case.

Comment: how are you finding the element. Couldn't you construct the path while finding it?

Comment: This is easy to do using XSLT -- see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java