# continuous integration for xml transformations

Tags: xml, xslt, continuous-integration

Hullo:
I am looking for a continuous integration tool for XML transformations. At the office, we use Atlassian Bamboo, which serves the purposes well:

1. We monitor a repo for pushes of XML documents
2. We have Ant targets that deal with the XSL Transformations over the pushed XML
3. Everyone's happy

Not so fast. How can we build tests on this? Ant does not `exit != 0` if it does not find an XML file, neither if the file is misconstructed and it fails to parse it.

We would have to make some tool that reads the build plan's logs, catches any [Error] or [Warn] messages from Ant and provide logic to produce alerts. Moreover, I think such tool should be compatible with JUnit or similar so that Bamboo may run it as a test.

So I wonder: have you seen any continuous integration tool prepared to deal with XML conversions? Or should I stop drifting and start scipting?

Comment: One can build a verifier for XSLT transformations, based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4747858/36305 -- I have done so and this is avery useful tool in real production software development environment.

Comment: That seems nice. I'll give it a shoot.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest integrating [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) into your build process. There is a XML plugin available that can be used to check for XML validation and additional checks. If any of these rules are broken there is another plugin that can fail your build.

- [SonarXML plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarXML)
- [Build breaker](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker) (not available any more from the Marketplace, see [SonarQube / Plugins library / Other Plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Other+Plugins))