# Get xpath from search result of a specific regex pattern in a bunch of xml files

Tags: php, python, xml, regex, xpath

I have many XML files, and i have to search in these files a string (in detail that will be a not-too-complicated regex).

With the results i want to get the xpath of the node in which the string is, i.e.:

```
pattern = /home|house/

files: file1.xml, file2.xml etc
```

Results:

```
"home" in file1.xml, xpath: //root/cars/car[2]
"house" in file2.xml, xpath: //root[1]/elemA[2][@attribute1='first']
```

How can i achieve this? I can use PHP, python, Javascript, VIM plugin (because i already worked with those)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP: [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) the XML files, [`xpath`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) all nodes, [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) their text and if matches, get the nodes' xpath with [`getNodePath()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014917/367456) and output it:

```
$pattern = '/home|house|guide/iu';

foreach (glob('data/*.xml') as $file)
{
    foreach (simplexml_load_file($file)->xpath('//*') as $node)
    {
        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $node, $matches)) continue;

        printf(
            "\"%s\" in %s, xpath: %s\n", implode('", "', $matches[0]),
            basename($file), dom_import_simplexml($node)->getNodePath()
        );
    }
}
```

Result (exemplary):

```
"Guide" in iana-charsets-2013-03-05.xml, xpath: /*/*[7]/*[158]/*[4]
"Guide" in iana-charsets-2013-03-05.xml, xpath: /*/*[7]/*[224]/*[2]
"Guide" in iana-charsets-2013-03-05.xml, xpath: /*/*[7]/*[224]/*[4]
"guide" in rdf-dmoz.xml, xpath: /*/*[4]/d:Description
"guide" in rdf-dmoz.xml, xpath: /*/*[5]/d:Description
```

Nice question btw.

Comment: accepted because it's the simplest, but @Wrikken answer is good too!

Comment: Yes the answer by him is good, too. Both together should leave some good inspiration for future users.

Answer (score 3):

Search:

```
 //*[contains('home') or contains('house')]
```

In PHP:

Use DOMDocument & DOMXPath, and then just call `DOMNode::getNodePath()` on the resulting matches.

If you actually need a regex instead of those matches earlier, php's DOMDocument only has XPATH 1.0 functions, but you can add functionality to DOMXPath by adding a user defined function with `DOMXPath::registerPhpFunctions`

Whipping up something quick without to much error handling:

```
function xpathregexmatch($nodelist,$regex){
        foreach($nodelist as $node){
                if( $node instanceof DOMText && preg_match($regex,$node->nodeValue)) return true;
        }
        return false;
}

foreach(glob('*.xml') as $file){
        $d = new DOMDocument();
        $d->load($file);
        $x = new DOMXPath($d);
        $x->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
        $x->registerPHPFunctions('xpathregexmatch');
        $matches = $x->query('//*[php:function("xpathregexmatch",text(),"/house|home/")]');
        if($matches->length){
                foreach($matches as $node){
                        echo $file. ':'.$node->getNodePath().PHP_EOL;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i'll got it! very helpful. i'll try to do it and let you know!

Comment: You could also use `functionString` and `preg_match()` directly instead of having the `xpathregexmatch()` function.

Comment: @salathe: good point, always forget about `functionString`... _But_: `$x->query('//*[php:functionString("preg_match","/wh[ab]t/",text())]');` or `$x->query('//*[php:functionString("preg_match","/wh[ab]t/",.)]');
` also select all parent nodes because it then probably looks at `->textContent`...

Comment: @Wrikken no, it's because `preg_match()` returns 0 or 1 (or false); you'll want to check the return value inside the predicate if going down that route: `//*[php:functionString("preg_match", "/house|home/", text()) = "1"]`   (or go wild and use `[boolean(number(php:functionString(…)))]`).

Comment: Ah. glad I ran into you today... Yes, less type-juggling it was... `//*[php:functionString("preg_match","/wh[ab]t/",text()) = "1"]` works then ;)

Comment: You don't need to check for length as you `froeach` later on. However I find the stringyfication of SimpleXML useful to give this a bit more of a cross-over: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15262125/367456

Comment: @hakre: yeah, that's because `foreach`ing over empty arrays generates notices... so I check anything for content before a `foreach`, be it an actual array, or just iterable.

Comment: No notice for empty array in foreach. Also this one is an iteator, It should be really without any notice even if there is no match (only if the xpath fails, but then `$matches->length` won't work, too).

Answer (score 0):

php simplexml:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string("file1.xml");
foreach ($xml->cars->car[2] as $car) {
    // do sth with $car
}
```

For more, be more specific with your question, please.

Comment: please read carefully, i don't have the xpath, i want to get it from search results