# Searching XML tags with regex - PHP XPatch

Tags: php, xml, regex, search, xpath

I have a XML document:

```
<product>
    <item>
        <item00>
            <name>DVD</name>
        </item00>
    </item>
</product>
<product>
    <item>
        <item11>
            <name>CD</name>
        </item11>
    </item>
</product>
```

And I would like to show the names of these products, but there are products with item as "**item00**" and "**item11**".

I tried adding the path regular expressions in XPath, but without success.

There is a possibility I display the name of these products (DVD and CD) using XPath?

```
<?php
$xml = 'file.xml';
$content = '';
$f = fopen($xml, 'r');

while($data = fread($f, filesize($xml))) {
    $content.= $data;
}
fclose($f);

preg_match_all('/\<product\>(.*?)\<\/product\>/s', $content, $product);

$product = $product[1];

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($content);

for($i = 0; $i <= count($product) - 1; $i++) {
    // So far, no problems. Seriously.
    // The issue starts here.
    $query = $doc->xpath('/product/item/???');

    foreach($query as $item) {
        echo $item->name . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Where "???" is the problem with "item00" and "item11".

If anyone knows and can help me, I'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here is the total working code 

<?php
$xml = 'file.xml';
$content = '';
$f = fopen($xml, 'r');

while($data = fread($f, filesize($xml))) {
    $content.= $data;
}
fclose($f);
$content = "<root>$conten</root>";
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$query = $doc->xpath('//item/child::*');
foreach($query as $item) {
    echo $item->name . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can use regex in that context, that's the very reason to use attributes

```
<item num="00">
```

however check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259746/get-xpath-from-search-result-of-a-specific-regex-pattern-in-a-bunch-of-xml-files#15262125), i believe it is what you are looking for

those 00 11 things really should be attributes