# XML - finding the path traversed for a given node

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I have an xml something like

```
<Screen>
    <window name="gui">
        <widget name="status" pos="0:0">
            <timedate name="timedate"/>
            <message name="message"/>
        </widget>
    </window>
</Screen>
```

One good thing about this xml is that every node has unique name. It will not repeat anywhere in the xml.

To find a node, I can query using xpath and will get the result for its presence/absence, But I need to find the path traversed.

example I can search the timedate node using xpath query '//timedate', but along with this I also need the path traversed i.e. Screen/window/widget/timedate.

Please suggest me some ways to retrieve the path also.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: ancestor-or-self::timedate -- this axis gives you the way from the element to the document element.. I am not that sure if the expression is right as it is but the axis is. If you can get a ordered list you should get a result beginning at the root going down to the <timedate> the path than becomes somthing like list.join('/'), but that is javascript like, I do not know perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exact details depend on what module you use to process XML. For example, in [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), you can use the `pwd` command.

A more verbose [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML) example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

use XML::LibXML;

my $x = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'example.xml');
my $n = $x->find('//timedate')->shift;
say $n->nodePath;
```

Answer (score 1):

**See this answer for a full solution**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747858/36305.

While the solution is in XSLT, the code can be converted to any other programming language, if necessary.

Comment: great solution, and thanks for your prompt reply. But this time, I was looking something in Perl itself. I wish I could also mark this answer as accepted too :)

Answer (score 0):

CPAN has a tool for that, [xpathify](https://metacpan.org/module/xpathify), which itself is a part of the [HTML::Untemplate](https://metacpan.org/module/SYP/HTML-Untemplate-0.015/lib/HTML/Untemplate.pod) package:

[image: screenshot]