# How to counting nodes by name in xml file by xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new with xsl . I am having below xml:

```
    <record>
<fruit>Apples</fruit>
<fruit>Oranges</fruit>
<fruit>Bananas</fruit>
<fruit>Plums</fruit>
<vegetable>Carrots</vegetable>
<vegetable>Peas</vegetable>
<candy>Snickers</candy>
```

I want to use key function and have an output file:

```
     <record> 1
--<fruit> 4
--<vegetable> 2
--<candy> 1
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Are those hyphens part of the expected output? Do you really want output with unclosed XML tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the hyphens (I will use Dimitre's answer as a base, so please give him the credit he is due), you can do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="*" use="name()"/>

  <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('kElemByName',name())[1]))]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="hyphens" />

    <xsl:value-of select=
       "concat('&lt;',name(),'> ', count(key('kElemByName',name())),'&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="hyphens">
    <xsl:text>--</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the original input, this produces:

```
<record> 1
--<fruit> 4
--<vegetable> 2
--<candy> 1
```

With a more deeply nested input,

```
<record>
  <fruit>
    Apples
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <citrus>Grapefruits</citrus>
    <citrus>Oranges</citrus>
    <citrus>Lemons</citrus>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>Bananas</fruit>
  <fruit>
    <pitted>Plums</pitted>
    <pitted>Apricots</pitted>
    <pitted>Peaches</pitted>
  </fruit>
  <vegetable>Carrots</vegetable>
  <vegetable>Peas</vegetable>
  <candy>
    <chocolate>Snickers</chocolate>
    <chocolate>Milky Way</chocolate>
    <chocolate>Hersheys</chocolate>
  </candy>
  <candy>
    <hard>Lozenges</hard>
    <hard>Lollipops</hard>
  </candy>
</record>
```

You get:

```
<record> 1
--<fruit> 4
----<citrus> 3
----<pitted> 3
--<vegetable> 2
--<candy> 2
----<chocolate> 3
----<hard> 2
```

How's that?

Comment: +1 for the `<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*" mode="hyphens" />` - very elegant, and an idiom I will have to remember for future reference.

Comment: Thanks @IanRoberts! Here's another case where I used a similar technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14274683/1945651  In this post here, a `<xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*"><xsl:text>--<xsl:text></xsl:for-each>` could've been just as good, but the other thread actually makes use of the template in more than one place.

Answer (score 2):

**As easy as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:key name="kElemByName" match="*" use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('kElemByName',name())[1]))]"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat('&lt;',name(),'> ', count(key('kElemByName',name())),'&#xA;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<record>
    <fruit>Apples</fruit>
    <fruit>Oranges</fruit>
    <fruit>Bananas</fruit>
    <fruit>Plums</fruit>
    <vegetable>Carrots</vegetable>
    <vegetable>Peas</vegetable>
    <candy>Snickers</candy>
</record>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<record> 1
<fruit> 4
<vegetable> 2
<candy> 1
```

Comment: Can you show me the way have result:/n
<record> 1
--<fruit> 4
--<veget> 2
--<candi> 1