# How to get list tag as array of objects using XPath?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, xpath

I am trying to extract the ordered list and return an array of list tags & content inside. I have already tried these paths,

1. `//li[div/@class="business-info"]`
2. `//li[div[@class="business-info"]]`
3. `//li[descendant::div[@class="business-info"]]`
4. `//li[div[@class="business-info"]/h2/a]`

Is this the right approach or should I go with `RegExp`? I am sharing my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/fb9d5rqz/) to have a drill down.

**Code**

```
const IGNORE = ['style', 'script'];
const NONWHITESPACE_RE = /\S/;
const result = document.evaluate(
    '//*[child::text()]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
);
const businessInfo = [];
for (let i = 0, j = result.snapshotLength; i < j; i++) {
    const element = result.snapshotItem(i);
    if (IGNORE.includes(element.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
        continue;
    }
    const nodes = [...element.childNodes];
    for (const node of nodes) {
        if (node.nodeType !== document.TEXT_NODE) {
            continue;
        }
        if (node.nodeValue.search(NONWHITESPACE_RE) === -1) {
            continue;
        }
        businessInfo.push({
            tag: element.tagName.toLowerCase(),
            text: node.nodeValue.trim()
        });
    }
}
console.log(businessInfo);
```

**HTML**

```
<ol class="results">
    <li class="result clearfix">
        <div class="business-info">
            <h2 itemprop="name">
                <a class="name" href="#">Company Ltd</a>
            </h2>
            <a href="#" class="phone disabled"><span class="tel-icon sprite"></span><span itemprop="telephone" class="phone">0123456789</span></a>
            <div class="address">
                <span class="address-main"><span itemprop="streetAddress">21 Largo Road</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">Focus</span>, </span>
                &nbsp;<span class="postcode" itemprop="postalCode">KY168NH</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="result clearfix">
        <div class="business-info">
            <h2 itemprop="name">
                <a class="name" href="#">Shipment Ltd</a>
            </h2>
            <a href="#" class="phone disabled"><span class="tel-icon sprite"></span><span itemprop="telephone" class="phone">0123456789</span></a>
            <div class="address">
                <span class="address-main"><span itemprop="streetAddress">ECR Road</span>, <span itemprop="addressLocality">St Andrews</span>, </span>
                &nbsp;<span class="postcode" itemprop="postalCode">800826</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**Expected Output: Array of Objects**

```
const businessInfo = [
    {
        name: 'Company Ltd',
        phone: '0123456789',
        address: '21 Largo Road',
        locality: 'Focus',
        postal: 'KY168NH'
    },
    {
        name: 'Company Ltd1',
        phone: '0123456789',
        address: 'ECR Road',
        locality: 'St Andrews',
        postal: '800826'
    },
];
```

These are the sources I took for reference

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/snapshotItem
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult/iterateNext
3. [Get XPath of XML Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435767/get-xpath-of-xml-tag)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your code in jfiddle seems to work.

Comment: @JackFleeting I expect output something similar to an array of objects that shared here in question.

Comment: Automatically I don't see how, i.e. how should something like attribute `itemprop='streetAddress'` map to your wanted object property `address`

Comment: XPath expressions select node sets or generate scalar values (string, number, boolean). The concept of array is not the same as set. Also, node sets results should be exchanged throught an API strong enough to be transformed into XPath data model and back, like DOM API. For DOM to JSON see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504050/how-to-convert-selected-html-to-json and for problems see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303713/how-to-serialize-dom-node-to-json-even-if-there-are-circular-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look's like there is no need of XPath for my case I solved it by finding an `innerText` for each property with the help of selector. And then I composed an array of objects with these properties. Now the output will be what I actually expected.

```
const businessInfo = [];
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('ol > li > div.business-info');
elements.forEach((element) => {
    const companyInfo = {};
    try {
        businessInfo.name = element.querySelector('h2 > a').innerText;
        businessInfo.phone = element.querySelector('a > span.phone').innerText;
        businessInfo.address = element.querySelector('div > span.address-main > span:nth-child(1)').innerText;
        businessInfo.locality = element.querySelector('div > span.address-main > span:nth-child(2)').innerText;
        businessInfo.postalCode = element.querySelector('div > span.postcode').innerText;
    } catch (exception) {

    }
    data.push(businessInfo);
});
console.log(businessInfo);
```

Comment: Using CSS selectors or XPath expressions would be the same, because you have built the result object your self, property by property.