# Generate xpath of XML using XSLT for all Nodes

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I was trying to find a way to convert the XML tags to their respective unique address like xPath. Nd I found an XSLT, where XML is processed and the unique address is created only for the nodes which doesnt have child elements and with attributes. [link]:[Generate/get xpath from XML node java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java)

XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vApos">'</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="*[@* or not(*)] ">
      <xsl:if test="not(*)">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat('=',$vApos,.,$vApos)"/>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vnumPrecSiblings" select=
         "count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vnumPrecSiblings">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $vnumPrecSiblings +1, ']')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[@',name(), '=',$vApos,.,$vApos,']')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when passed to this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <main>
        <tag1>001</tag1>
        <tag2>002</tag2>
        <tag3>
        <tag4>004</tag4>
        </tag3>
        <tag2>002</tag2>
        <tag5>005</tag5>
    </main>
</root>
```

produces

```
/root/main/tag1='001' /root/main/tag2='002' /root/main/tag3/tag4='004' /root/main/tag2[2]='002' /root/main/tag5='005'
```

So I need the xslt to generate in the following way

```
/root
/root/main
/root/main/tag1
/root/main/tag2
/root/main/tag3
/root/main/tag3/tag4
/root/main/tag2[2]
/root/main/tag5
```

Also I dont need values. So please help me with this

Answer (score 4):

Your result could be produced rather simply by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])"/>
        <xsl:if test="$i">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $i + 1, ']')"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this does not process attributes (or any other type of nodes other than elements).