# How I get path in xml

Tags: java, xml

I have XML that Structure like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <root>
   <child1 name="1"/>
   <child2 name="2"/>
   <child3 name="3">
          <condition>x>=50</condition>
          <childofchild3 name="3.1">
             <condition>y<40</condition>
                <childOfchild3.1 name="3.1.1">
                   <condition>a>70</condition>
                      <step>
                        <a1>
                          <aa1> </aa1>
                        </a1>   
                        <b1 />
                      </step>

                     <c1>
                       <a1>
                         <aa1> </aa1>
                       </a1>    
                     </c1>
             </childOfchild3.1>
            <c1>
              <a1>
                <aa1> </aa1>
              </a1> 
            </c1>
          </childOfchild3>
          <c1>
             <a1>
                <aa1> </aa1>
             </a1>  
         </c1>
   </child3>
   <child4 name="4" />
 </root>
```

I have to print nodes path with value using java. Here is the sample of output I have to get:

```
child1 -> child2 -> child3 -> childOfchild3 -> chileOfchild3.1 -> a1 -> b1  -> child4
child1 -> child2 -> child3 -> childOfchild3 -> chileOfchild3.1 -> c1 -> a1-> child4
child1 -> child2 -> child3 -> childOfchild3 -> c1 -> a1-> child4
child1 -> child2 -> child3 -> c1 -> a1-> child4
```

This is last java code but it can't work correctly

```
public class xmlPath{
static List <String []> valueList = new ArrayList<String []>() ;
static String rootPath = "";
    public static void showPath (){
        try{
        File xml = new File("test.xml");

        String nextNode="";
        DocumentBuilderFactory   dbFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml);
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        rootPath += "root";
        NodeList sequenceList = doc.getElementsByTagName("root");
        Element sequenceNode = (Element) sequenceList.item(0);
        NodeList sequenceChildList =  sequenceNode.getChildNodes();

        for(int i=0;i<sequenceChildList.getLength();i++){

             if(sequenceChildList.item(i) instanceof Element && sequenceChildList.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){

                 nextNode = rootPath+" > "+ sequenceChildList.item(i).getNodeName(); 

                    if(sequenceChildList.item(i).hasChildNodes()){
                        findPath(sequenceChildList.item(i).getChildNodes(), nextNode);
                    }
                    else{
                      if(sequenceChildList.item(i).hasAttributes()){        
                             NamedNodeMap nameAttr = sequenceChildList.item(i).getAttributes();
                              for(int j=0;j<nameAttr.getLength();j++){
                                  Node node = nameAttr.item(j);
                                 if ("name".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                                    valueList.add(new String []{nextNode,node.getNodeValue()}); 

                                    }
                              }
                         } 


                    }
             }
        }
        Iterator <String []> iT = valueList.iterator();
        for(;iT.hasNext();){
            String [] val = iT.next();
            if(!val[0].contains("condition")){
            System.out.println(val[0]+" = "+val[1]);
          }
        }
        } catch(Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void findPath(NodeList seQuenceList,String listPath){
        String path, value,count,name=null;
        Node nextNode;
        for(int i=0;i<seQuenceList.getLength();i++){


            if(seQuenceList.item(i) instanceof Element){

                path = listPath+" > "+seQuenceList.item(i).getNodeName();


                    if(seQuenceList.item(i).getChildNodes().getLength() >=1){

                        findPath(seQuenceList.item(i).getChildNodes(), path);
                    }

                    else if(!seQuenceList.item(i).hasChildNodes()){
                        nextNode= nextNode(seQuenceList.item(i));
                            if(nextNode !=null){
                                findPath(nextNode.getChildNodes(), listPath);
                            }
                            if(nextNode ==null){

                                System.out.println("Not chileNode");
                                valueList.add(new String []{listPath,name});
                            }  

                    }                               
            }
        } 
    }
    public static Node nextNode(Node currentNode){
            Node nextNode = currentNode.getNextSibling();
            if(currentNode.getNodeType() ==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                while(!(nextNode instanceof Element) && nextNode != null){
                    nextNode = nextNode.getNextSibling();
                }
            }
            return nextNode;
    }
```

This is actual output.

```
child1
child2
child3 -> childOfchild3 -> childOfchild3.1 -> a1 -> aa1
chile3 -> childOfchild3 -> childOfchild3.1 -> c1 -> a1 -> aa1
child3 -> childOfchild3 -> c1 -> a1 -> aa1
child3 -> c1 -> a1 -> aa1
child4
```

Plese help me to make it correctly. Not need use recursion to solve problem. thanks.

Comment: Could you tidy up the `child` `chile` confusion?

Comment: Further, could you explain why a sibling relationship (`child1` and `child2`) seems to be represented the same way as a parent relationship (`child3` and `childof3`), what's the logic here? And why are some tags simply skipped (such as `step`) in the output?

Comment: child1 and child2 has same parent is root and some tags that disappear in path i don't interes to show. and (child3 and childof3) i mean childof3 has parent node is child3 i'am sorry if you don't understand or confuse.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I edited xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilder builder = JOOX.builder();
        Document xmlExampleDocument = builder.parse(XMLTEST.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample.xml"));
        List<String> doneList = $(xmlExampleDocument).xpath("//*[not(*)]").map(context -> $(context).xpath() + "='" + $(context).text() + "'");
        for (String x : doneList) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Your XML is malformed. Fix it.
 2. Consider using JOOX API  :  compile 'org.jooq:joox:1.2.0'
 3. Sample code shared.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I never use JOOX API. Amit Parashar plese help me one more time. Now i use DOM to solve problem

Comment: In that case, Please follow the solution from Blaise Doughan at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java. This works great.

Comment: Why would you use IOUtils to convert an InputStream into a String, then into bytes (using the default charset, which is usually unsafe), then into an InputStream again?  getResourceAsStream already returns a perfectly usable and parseable InputStream.

Comment: @VGR. Actually I just pulled the sample code from JOOX test class. https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOX/blob/master/jOOX/src/test/java/org/joox/test/JOOXTest.java. You are right, this was not required. Thanks. Fixed it now.