# How to get a unique value from the expected result and compare it with the expected result?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a code such as below:

```
<abc>
<aaa>123</aaa>
</abc>
<abc>
<aaa>123</aaa>
</abc>
```

When I give the XPath expression as:

```
//*[name() = 'aaa']
```

I get the output as

```
{'123','123'}
```

What I want is to get only one result from the XPath expression so that I can compare it with a property that I give as expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can simply use `//aaa`, to select all `aaa` elements. If you only want the first selected element then use `(//aaa)[1]`.

Comment: I dont want the element. I want the value in the element.

Comment: Which XPath version and which host language do you use?

Comment: @IrineMathew - Try adding `text()` to the path: `(//aaa)[1]/text()`

Comment: @DanielHaley, if its XPath 1.0 then doing `string(//aaa)` or `number(//aaa)` seems more appropriate if a primitive value is needed as the result. With XPath 2.0 I would use `(//aaa/data(.))[1]`.

Comment: @IrineMathew, your original expression `//*[name() = 'aaa']` selects element nodes as well, so if that worked, I don't see why my suggestion selecting the first element should not do. If you want a primitive value like a string or a number then see my suggestion in the comment to Daniel.

Comment: @DanielHaley - Your solution worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @IrineMathew - It's really Martin's solution so please accept his answer. He also has very good points in his comment to me, so be sure to read it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747858/36305

It demonstrates a way, using XSLT, to build an XPath expression for selecting every node of a given XML document and even generating an XPath expression for comparing the values:

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vApos">'</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="*[@* or not(*)] ">
      <xsl:if test="not(*)">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat('=',$vApos,.,$vApos)"/>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vnumPrecSiblings" select=
         "count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name(current())])"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vnumPrecSiblings">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', $vnumPrecSiblings +1, ']')"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('[@',name(), '=',$vApos,.,$vApos,']')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided input** (wrapped in a top-element to become well-formed):

```
<t>
    <abc>
        <aaa>123</aaa>
    </abc>
    <abc>
        <aaa>123</aaa>
    </abc>
</t>
```

**the result is a set of XPath expressions selecting each of the elements** that have a single text child, and comparing the string value of the element and the child:

```
/t/abc/aaa='123'
/t/abc[2]/aaa='123'
```

**This also generates expressions, that involve comparisons of attribute values**, and whose Boolean value is `true()` exactly when the attribute value comparison is true.

**For example, if the provided XML document was this**:

```
<t>
    <abc x="1" y="2">
        <aaa>123</aaa>
    </abc>
    <abc z="3">
        <aaa>123</aaa>
    </abc>
</t>
```

**then the result of the transformation is**:

```
/t/abc[@x='1']
/t/abc[@y='2']
/t/abc/aaa='123'
/t/abc[2][@z='3']
/t/abc[2]/aaa='123'
```