# Get Absolute XPath of WebElement in Java

Tags: java, html, xpath

I know how to get the absolute XPath of an element via `Javascript` using the following code:

```
public String getAbsoluteXPath(WebDriver driver)
{
    return  (String) driver.executeScript(
            "function absoluteXPath(element) {"+
                    "var comp, comps = [];"+
                    "var parent = null;"+
                    "var xpath = '';"+
                    "var getPos = function(element) {"+
                    "var position = 1, curNode;"+
                    "if (element.nodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {"+
                    "return null;"+
                    "}"+
                    "for (curNode = element.previousSibling; curNode; curNode = curNode.previousSibling){"+
                    "if (curNode.nodeName == element.nodeName) {"+
                    "++position;"+
                    "}"+
                    "}"+
                    "return position;"+
                    "};"+

"if (element instanceof Document) {"+
"return '/';"+
"}"+

"for (; element && !(element instanceof Document); element = element.nodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE ? element.ownerElement : element.parentNode) {"+
"comp = comps[comps.length] = {};"+
"switch (element.nodeType) {"+
"case Node.TEXT_NODE:"+
"comp.name = 'text()';"+
"break;"+
"case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:"+
"comp.name = '@' + element.nodeName;"+
"break;"+
"case Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:"+
"comp.name = 'processing-instruction()';"+
"break;"+
"case Node.COMMENT_NODE:"+
"comp.name = 'comment()';"+
"break;"+
"case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:"+
"comp.name = element.nodeName;"+
"break;"+
"}"+
"comp.position = getPos(element);"+
"}"+

"for (var i = comps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {"+
"comp = comps[i];"+
"xpath += '/' + comp.name.toLowerCase();"+
"if (comp.position !== null) {"+
"xpath += '[' + comp.position + ']';"+
"}"+
"}"+

"return xpath;"+

"} return absoluteXPath(arguments[0]);", this.element);

}
```

However, I am not sure how I could do this directly via Java if for instance I had access to the `HTML source`.

How could it be done?

The absolute XPath of the Logo on Google.com would be:

```
html/body/div[1]/div[6]/span/center/div[1]/img
```

Whereas the relative XPath of Google Logo is: `.//*[@id='hplogo']`

How can I obtain the absolute XPath of a web element given the element + HTML?

Thanks

Comment: [Generate/get xpath from XML node java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746299/generate-get-xpath-from-xml-node-java) ?

Comment: Do you need to solve this problem using Java programming only or do you have the leverage to use some other tools as well?

Comment: @AnilChandna Preferably using Java itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below logic helps

```
function absolutePath(element) {
    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'html')
        return '/html[1]';
    if (element === document.body)
        return '/html[1]/body[1]';
    var ix = 0;
    var siblings = element.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
        var sibling = siblings[i];
        if (sibling === element)
            return absolutePath(element.parentNode) + '/' + element.tagName.toLowerCase() + '[' + (ix + 1) + ']';
        if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling.tagName.toLowerCase() === element.tagName.toLowerCase())
            ix++;
    }
}
```

Its a much more simplified version