# Is any way serah match value from root node by xmlstarlet and return XPATH

Tags: xmlstarlet

As title

I am resarch xmlstartle, but seems no way to serach value from root node then return XPATH
Is any idea?

ThanksPeter

Comment: Perhaps you're after something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747858 "Generate/get xpath from XML"), an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make use of this example which handles elements and
attributes but *not* other node types. Assuming a POSIX shell,
indentation and line continuation characters added for readability.

```
xmlstarlet select --text -t \
  -m '//xsl:*/@test[contains(.,"position")]' \
    -m 'ancestor-or-self::*' \
      --var pos='1+count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])' \
      -v 'concat("/",name(),"[",$pos,"]")' \
    -b \
    --if 'count(. | ../@*) = count(../@*)' \
      -v 'concat("/@",name())' \
    -b \
    -n \
/usr/share/*/xslt/docbook/common/db-common.xsl
```

Where:

- the outer `-m (--match)` option specifies the target, with optional
  search conditions given as
  [predicates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#predicates)
- the inner `-m (--match)` builds the XPath of elements from root to target,
  calculating position by counting siblings
- for an attribute node target - which doesn't match `ancestor-or-self::*` -
  the `-i (--if)` clause adjusts the XPath
- a `-C (--comp)` option before `-t` lists the generated XSLT code

Output:

```
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[2]/xsl:for-each[1]/xsl:if[1]/@test
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[3]/xsl:for-each[1]/xsl:if[1]/@test
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[7]/xsl:for-each[1]/xsl:choose[1]/xsl:when[1]/@test
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[7]/xsl:for-each[1]/xsl:choose[1]/xsl:when[3]/@test
```

Output from outer `-m '//xsl:param[string(@select)]'`:

```
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[1]/xsl:param[1]
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[4]/xsl:param[1]
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[5]/xsl:param[1]
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[5]/xsl:param[2]
/xsl:stylesheet[1]/xsl:template[6]/xsl:param[1]
```